# Multiple UIWebViews in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Can anyone point me in a direction to start with the following:

I have five `UIWebView`s, each of which is correctly sizing to content, inside of a `UIScrollView`. The `UIWebView`s display text only and since they are correctly sized to content, do not allow scrolling. I calculate the position of each `UIWebView` based upon the position and height of the previous `UIWebView`.

This works fine when all five `UIWebView`s fit within the bounds of the `UIScrollView` but I am not sure

1. How to position them when they exceed the vertical bounds of the `UIScrollView`
2. How to get the `UIScrollView` to actually scroll the contents.

I am working with someone who would like the `UIWebView`s to be separate controls for subsequent handling - highlighting and some oother functionality.

Comment: Could you either post a relevant sample of your code, or provide a link to a code posting site (ie. pastebin or gist) if the code is sufficiently lengthy?